# Angular AOT guard throwing errors if params not in use('next' is declared but never used)

Tags: angular, angular2-aot

I've just upgraded to Angular 4.1.1
From what i understand, AOT is now on by default(which is great).

I have a guard that don't use the next param.

If i try to run the code as is i get `'next' is declared but never used.`
 error.

If i remove the 'next' param i get this error:
`Class 'AuthGuard' incorrectly implements interface 'CanActivate'.`

This is the guard's code:

```
@Injectable()
export class AuthGuard implements CanActivate {
  constructor(private authService: AuthenticationService) {}
  canActivate(
    next: ActivatedRouteSnapshot,
    state: RouterStateSnapshot): Observable<boolean> | Promise<boolean> | boolean {
      return this.authService.guardCheck(state.url);
    }
}
```

What is the best way to handle this errors?

Comment: `'next' is declared but never used.` gives you a type error?

Comment: Yes. And it crashes the app

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If anyone encounter this issue, just remove `"noUnusedParameters": true,`
from tsconfig.ts